# SQLite database ..is the value of primary key effected if i delete a row from table

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

suppose i build a table with 10 rows initially. so the value of the id(primary key column) at the end will be 9 or 10 ? and now suppose i delete row no. 5 and 8 (assuming rows counting start from 1) and add one another row so that now i have 9 rows in total. now what will happen to the values of id in each row.?

```
      db.delete(DBAdapter.TableName, "Id=? AND QstnrId=? AND QstnId=?",
      new String[] { Id.toString(), QuestionnaireId, QuestionId });
```

Comment: What's wrong with trying it out?

Comment: The IDs will not be reassigned if that's what your asking... row id 10 will still be 10.

Answer (score 5):

the values of id for the earlier rows will remain same...

For new ones, it will start form 10/11...

so the list of ids would be : 1 2 3 4 6 7 9 10 11 12 ,....
`as in every other SQL Database`

Answer (score 4):

An **autoincrement primary key** column in SQLite uses a value 1 larger than the largest value that has ever been used in the table:

From [the documentation](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> If a column has the type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT then a slightly different ROWID selection algorithm is used. **The ROWID chosen for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has ever before existed in that same table.** If the table has never before contained any data, then a ROWID of 1 is used. If the table has previously held a row with the largest possible ROWID, then new INSERTs are not allowed and any attempt to insert a new row will fail with an SQLITE_FULL error.

So, deleting a row has no effect on the next ID generated.

Note: In the case of non-primary keys, it only uses the value of the current largest ID.

Also, deleting a row will not change the values of another row, so if you have ID's 1, 2, 3, 4 and delete the row with ID 1, the remaining rows will still have ID's 2, 3, 4. Auto-increment is just a method of making inserts easier.

Comment: thanx a lot ... specially for the documentation...:)

Answer (score 1):

The old ID values will not be affected.